# Can you control your Pi via SSH while it is off?

Tags: pi-4, ssh, raspberry-pi-desktop

This could possibly be a dumb question but I couldn't find an answer online for it. Is it possible that I could connect from my PC via SSH to my Raspberry Pi while it is off? I want to access the files on my Pi while it's off from school so I don't have to waste power keeping the Pi on all the time. I have a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B.

Answer (score 3):

No, for a Pi to do anything it requires power.